# OpenCV and Python: Connected components analysis

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have a working connected components analysis code working in C. It's actually a copy from the book "Learning Opencv".

Now I am rewriting all that code to Python and I cannot find some of that function in the Python API, like cvStartFindContours.

I am wondering is somebody has a basic connected components analysis function implemented in Python. I know there are some libraries, but I am searching for something simpler, just a function or a piece of code.

I don't need anything "big" because I have a plain black image with 2 or 3 white circles, and I want to find the number of circles and its center.

I know I can probably code on myself but I prefer to use somebody's function or simple library.

EDIT: I solved it the following way.

```
def find_connected_components(img):
    """Find the connected components in img being a binary image.
    it approximates by rectangles and returns its centers
    """

    storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
    contour = cv.FindContours(img, storage, cv.CV_RETR_CCOMP, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    centers = []

    while contour:
        # Approximates rectangles
        bound_rect = cv.BoundingRect(list(contour))

        centers.append(bound_rect[0] + bound_rect[2] / 2, bound_rect[1] + bound_rect[3] / 2)

        contour = contour.h_next()
```

Comment: Is the learning opencv book an O'reilly book? I'd like to get access to the connected components code for C or c++

Comment: avoid opencv's deprecated cv api by all means. it is removed already in opencv3.0

Comment: If you haven't checked the date, this post has more than 3 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the documentation. As of OpenCV 2.2 there is a complete new interface for Python which covers all C/C++ functions :)

[`cv.FindContours`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=FindContours#findcontours) should work for you :)

Answer (score 7):

There is BSD license connected components code (in Cython) as part of scikit-image:

https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/measure/_ccomp.pyx

If you have the package installed, it is as simple as

```
from skimage import measure
import numpy as np

L = measure.label(image)
print "Number of components:", np.max(L)
```

Answer (score 5):

a bit dated of a reply but there's also this patch:
http://code.opencv.org/attachments/467/opencv-connectedcomponents.patch

should be one of the faster implementations out there and still easy to call.
should be integrated into mainline sometime in the future...

edit: it's been in mainline for sometime waiting on 3.0 to release.  Don't ask me why they didn't release it earlier!

disclaimer - I'm the author :-)

Comment: The fastest connected component implementation is O(N), so I presume the one in skimage would perform very similarly to opencv's.

Comment: There's alot of them that are O(N) - 1 pass and 2 pass but in reality each one is quite a bit slower than eachother with context and implementation details.  I checked skimage's code and while short and implementing the same 2-pass method, it misses  the optimizations (decision trees, reduced loads from memory, reduced checks at runtime, less calculations, more immediate instructions) that make mine competitive with average/trivial case of the 1-pass algorithms which on context can happen alot.  You might scoff with O(N) but it makes the difference between 10 fps and 30 with this algorithm.

Comment: No scoffing; I appreciate the amount of effort you put into your implementation and the OP should, indeed, use it if applicable.

Comment: the URL is broken

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV 3.0.0-dev has [`connectedComponents`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=connectedcomponents#connectedcomponents) function but the doc says it is only for C++.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Stefan van der Walt answer, here's a bit longer skimage labeling example:

```
from skimage import morphology
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys


def get_image():
    size = (w, h) = (100, 100)
    img = np.zeros(size, np.uint8)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (10, 10), (19, 19), (128), -1)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (30, 20), (39, 39), (128), -1)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (40, 30), (49, 49), (128), -1)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (50, 70), (89, 79), (128), -1)
    return img


def show_image(img):
    cv2.imshow('result', img), cv2.waitKey(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = get_image()
    show_image(img)

    labels = morphology.label(img, background=0)
    label_number = 0
    while True:
        temp = np.uint8(labels==label_number) * 255
        if not cv2.countNonZero(temp):
            break
        show_image(temp)
        label_number += 1

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `connectedComponents` function in `OpenCV 3.0.0 - python` too.

[image: opencv python function list]